# How to find the index of a paragraph in word 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-addins, word-2010

I am reading a word document in c#,where after reading it, I need to enter a comment for selected paragraphs.

So I need to find the index of paragraph through c#, is it possible??

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph aPar in oDoc.Paragraphs) // looping through all the paragh in document
{
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range parRng = aPar.Range;
   string sText = parRng.Text;
   if (sText == para[1].ToString())   // found the paragraph and i need the index of this paragraph
   {
       oDoc.Comments.Add(oDoc.Paragraphs[0].Range, ref comments); // to add the comment in document
   }
}
```

If I found the index of that paragraph, Can I insert the comment on that paragraph? Is it possible?

Or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
              int i = 1;
              foreach (Word.Paragraph aPar in oDoc.Paragraphs)
              {
              string sText = aPar.Range.Text;
             if (sText != "\r")
             {
               if (sText == para[1].ToString() + "\r")
               {
               Word.Range range = oDoc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range;
               if (!range.Text.Contains("GUID:"))
                   {
                       int pEnd = aPar.Range.End;
                       string guid = "GUID:" + para[0].Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
                       int length = guid.Length;
                       aPar.Range.InsertAfter(guid);
                       Word.Range parRng = oDoc.Range(pEnd, pEnd + length);
                       parRng.Font.Hidden = 1;
                       parRng.InsertParagraphAfter();
                       }
                     }
                   }
                   i++;
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph aPar in oDoc.Paragraphs) // loads all words in document
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range parRng = aPar.Range;
        string sText = parRng.Text.Replace("\r","");
        if (sText == txtBoxParagraph.Text )   // found the paragraph and i need the index of this paragraph
        {
            oDoc.Comments.Add(parRng, txtBoxComments.Text);   // to add the comment in document
        }
    }
```

It works for me.